# Format String Exploitation - Unkown differences in leaked LIBC addresses

Tags: glibc, exploit

My goal is to get a better understanding of format string exploits.
While looking at different challenges, I always run into the same issue.
The information given below were obtained while solving the retired "Nightmare" pwn challenge from hackthebox, but I get the issue in other challenges as well. This example just serves as a reference.

The nightmare binary has the following protections:

> RELRO:    No RELRO
> Stack:    Canary found
> NX:       NX enabled
> PIE:      PIE enabled

The interesting part of the code is:

```
...
fgets(code, 6, stdin);
printf(code);
...
```

The goal is to overwrite a GOT entry.
One can download the Nightmare elf file for preparing the exploit and then has to run it against a server for obtaining the flag.
In this challenge no LIBC is provided for download so one has to determine the server version in the exploit process.

I did some enumeration locally to understand what values can be leaked via the printf call and the first 50 leaks are:

> 1 0xa702431
> 2 0xfbad2088
> 3 0xa702433
> 4 0x5555555592a5
> 5 0x21001
> 6 0xa70243625
> 7 (nil)
> 8 (nil)
> 9 (nil)
> 10 (nil)
> 11 (nil)
> 12 (nil)
> 13 (nil)
> 14 0x1
> 15 0x7ffff7df124a <__libc_start_call_main+122>:    0x2fe8c789
> 16 (nil)
> 17 0x555555555149 : 0xe5894855
> 18 0x100000000
> 19 0x7fffffffde58: 0xffffe2a0
> 20 0x7fffffffde58: 0xffffe2a0
> 21 0xd6f49242d225c3e
> 22 (nil)
> 23 0x7fffffffde68: 0xffffe2f0
> 24 0x555555557dd8
> 25 0x7ffff7ffd020 <_rtld_global>: 0xf7ffe2f0
> 26 0xae241031bf9d82f8
> 27 0xb238f83ac87fe046
> 28 (nil)
> 29 (nil)
> 30 (nil)
> 31 0x7fffffffde58: 0xffffe2a0
> 32 0x7fffffffde58: 0xffffe2a0
> 33 0x37407f72d1b00700
> 34 0xd
> 35 0x7ffff7df1305 <__libc_start_main_impl+133>: 0x643d8b4c
> 36 0x555555555149 : 0xe5894855
> 37 0x555555557dd8
> 38 (nil)
> 39 (nil)
> 40 (nil)
> 41 0x555555555060 <_start>: 0x8949ed31
> 42 0x7fffffffde50: 0xffffe28c
> 43 (nil)
> 44 (nil)
> 45 0x555555555081 <_start+33>: 0x0f2e66f4
> 46 0x7fffffffde48: 0xffffe273
> 47 0x7ffff7fc3160: 0xf7dca000
> 48 0x1
> 49 0x7fffffffe1d7: 0x5455415f
> 50 (nil)

Based on this output, the idea would be to chose suitable leaks for determining the LIBC version on the remote server.
My local test system is Parrot OS 6.0 with the LIBC version "Debian GLIBC 2.36-9+deb12u4".
If I patch the local Nightmare elf file to have it use the LIBC file from the server (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu), I get the following leaks:

> 1 0x555555556079
> 2 0x6c
> 3 0xffffffff
> 4 0x7fffffffdcc2:    0x00000004
> 5 (nil)
> 6 0xa702436255500
> 7 0x683888d743a72400
> 8 0x7fffffffdcf0: 0xffffdd98
> 9 0x5555555554d5: 0x8d481beb
> 10 0x7fffffffdde0: 0xffffe298
> 11 0x3200000000000000
> 12 (nil)
> 13 0x7ffff7dfc0b3 <__libc_start_main+243>: 0x06e8c789
> 14 0x7ffff7ffc620 <_rtld_global_ro>: 0x00000000
> 15 0x7fffffffdde8: 0xffffe2cc
> 16 0x100000000
> 17 0x555555555478: 0xfa1e0ff3
> 18 0x555555555500: 0xfa1e0ff3
> 19 0x9a65c3e7407b898f
> 20 0x555555555180: 0xfa1e0ff3
> 21 0x7fffffffdde0: 0xffffe298
> 22 (nil)
> 23 (nil)
> 24 0xafa33525bd465d0c
> 25 0x954e9f04b050d755
> 26 (nil)
> 27 (nil)
> 28 (nil)
> 29 0x1
> 30 0x7fffffffdde8: 0xffffe2cc
> 31 0x7fffffffddf8: 0xffffe312
> 32 0x7ffff7ffe190: 0x55554000
> 33 (nil)
> 34 (nil)
> 35 0x555555555180: 0xfa1e0ff3
> 36 0x7fffffffdde0: 0xffffe298
> 37 (nil)
> 38 (nil)
> 39 0x5555555551ae: 0x8d4890f4
> 40 0x7fffffffddd8: 0xffffe284
> 41 0x1c
> 42 0x1
> 43 0x7fffffffe16b: 0x5455415f
> 44 (nil)
> 45 0x7fffffffe1b6: 0x752d4543
> 46 0x7fffffffe1df: 0x00323333
> 47 0x7fffffffe231: 0x4c00726f
> 48 0x7fffffffe242: 0x3d4e4f49
> 49 0x7fffffffe255: 0x4552475f
> 50 0x7fffffffe26e: 0x696c2f62

So the leaked addresses are very different between both versions of LIBC.
In the solutions I found online, people always obtained output similar to the one of the server and used position 13 "0x7ffff7dfc0b3 <__libc_start_main+243>" and the online database libc.blukat.me to determine the LIBC server version. 
With my local output however, the leaks and the order of the leaks is just completely different.
For example, there is no leak to "__libc_start_main" at all in my local case but for example a leak to "__libc_start_call_main" at a differen position.
I do not understand how I can relate my local leaks and the server leaks to determine the LIBC version of the server.
I run into this problem pretty much at every challenge where I have to determine the LIBC version online. In the provided walkthroughs I never see anyone face my problem. Everyone seems to get leaks similar to the server ones regarding position and content.

What am I missing?